# Python: upload large files S3 fast

Tags: python, amazon-s3, upload, boto3

I am trying to upload programmatically an very large file up to 1GB on S3. As I found that AWS S3 supports multipart upload for large files, and I found some Python code to do it. ([link](https://gist.github.com/teasherm/bb73f21ed2f3b46bc1c2ca48ec2c1cf5) )

My point: the speed of upload was too slow (almost 1 min).

Is there any way to increase the performance of multipart upload. Or any good library support S3 uploading

Comment: I'd think your main limitations would be your Internet connection and your local network if you're using WiFi. It sounds like your getting close to 20Mb/sec upload speed which is hardly anything to scoff at. Have you tried speedtest to see what your Internet upload bandwidth is?

Comment: I used the office wifi for test, upload speed around 30Mps. What I want to do is optimise as much as possible the upload code, to deal with unsteady internet in real scenario

Comment: I also found is if I used the method "put_object", the upload speed is much faster, so I don't understand what is the point of multipart upload

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Leave my answer here for ref, the performance increase twice with this code:

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

S3_BUCKET = 'mybucket'
FILE_PATH = '/path/to/file/'
KEY_PATH = "/path/to/s3key/" 

def uploadFileS3(filename):
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024*25, max_concurrency=10,
                        multipart_chunksize=1024*25, use_threads=True)
    file = FILE_PATH + filename
    key = KEY_PATH + filename
    s3_client.upload_file(file, S3_BUCKET, key,
    ExtraArgs={ 'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType': 'video/mp4'},
    Config = config,
    Callback=ProgressPercentage(file)
    )

uploadFileS3('upload.mp4')
```

Special thank to @BryceH for suggestion. Although solution did increase the performance of S3 uploading, but I still open to receive any better solution. Thanks

Comment: this  solution looks elegant but its not working.The  response is NULL. So we request you to post answers whcih are verified method.

Comment: Just because it returns null doesn't mean it didn't work (it does).  For those looking for ProgressPercentage() it can be copy/pasted from https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html

Comment: `NameError: name 'ProgressPercentage' is not defined`

Comment: @Phong Vu the same TransferConfig don't work for download using boto3. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 4):

1 minute for 1 GB is quite fast for that much data over the internet. You should consider S3 transfer acceleration for this use case. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Comment: Yea, I will consider this configuration. Now I am focusing on coding.

Answer (score 0):

We can use python subprocess module to copy from one s3 bucket larger object file to another s3 bucket.

`import subprocess`

`subprocess.call(['aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://<bucketname>/temp/part-00000.csv', 's3://<bucketname>/temp/samp.csv'])`

100gb -->file copy---~6min

Great performance in run time.